# FFmpeg finish recording before than expected

Tags: raspbian, ffmpeg, camera

I'm using the following command over a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running raspbian stretch to record video from a USB webcam with ffmpeg

```bsh
ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -re -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f v4l2 -s 1280x720 -r 20 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -crf 26 -t 3600 output.mp4
```

And I obtain a mp4 file with a length of one hour, however, ffmpeg finish the recording in about 56 minutes, I don't know if that is normal but even if the video seems really smooth, and it actually last 1 hour, in real life, I'm missing 4 minutes of recording, that might be ok, but is there a way to avoid that?, I would feel better if I could get one real time hour and one hour length video.

In case of affirmative or negative answer (to my question if there is a way to avoid that), can someone explain me why that happens?

To give you details about the camera, it can record on mjpeg at 60 fps and only at 60 fps, I can see a warning from ffmpeg at the start saying it couldn't change the FPS of the video but still my output looks like is runnign at 20 FPS

Comment: For live input, don't use `-re`. Don't use `-r 20` when using `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1`

Comment: I wanted to set framerate to 20 to save CPU resources, searching on internet I found that ```-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1``` was useful to avoid what I'm experiencing, do you think is useful?, I would like to keep the framerate at 20 @Gyan

Comment: Use `-framerate 20` , not `-r 20` with capture devices. The latter will retime frames, not what you want.

Comment: I tested with the command ```ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -framerate 20 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f v4l2 -s 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -crf 26 -t 10 output.mp4```, and after 42 seconds ffmpeg stops and the output is 60 seconds long @Gyan